# select concat(first_name,' ',last_name) as "full name "from employees ---how to bring space when 2 columns are concatenated in oracle---

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select concat(first_name,' ',last_name) as "full name "from employees
```

Comment: `select first_name || ' ' || last_name as "full name "from employees`

Answer (score 6):

Oracle's `CONCAT` function takes only two arguments.  So if you wanted to continue along with your exact current approach, you would have to chain together two calls to `CONCAT`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(first_name, ' '), last_name) AS "full name"
FROM employees;
```

Or, you could just use the ANSI standard concatenation operator `||`:

```
SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name AS "full name"
FROM employees;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the operator `||`:

```
select (first_name || ' ' || last_name) as full_name
from employees
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the below using `||`

```
 select first_name || ' ' || last_name as "full name" from employees;
```

If you want to use [CONCAT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm) operator you can try the below:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(first_name , ' '),LAST_NAME) AS "full name"
      FROM employees;
```